# Is WebM live streaming supported on Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, webm

WebM is listed as a supported format on Chromecast, but does that include live webm files? I.e. a camera that generates a WebM file. Does it need to be formatted in a certain way, or is a custom receiver required?

I'm aware HLS and MPEG-DASH are available, but I'm exploring lower latency paths for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious it does, but pretty unstable. And definitely not low latency. Use WebRTC if low latency is desired (needs to be set up yourself in a custom receiver)